# 401 when calling UserInfo using ADFS 4.0 and OpenID Connect

Tags: adfs, openid-connect, windows-server-2016

I've successfully created a new Application Group with a Server Application as well as a Web API and the OpenID Connect protocol is working w/out any issues until I try and make a call to UserInfo.  The Relying Party identifier is the same GUID as Client ID of the Server Application (per the examples I have read online).  I get the error below when trying to call UserInfo:

`WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token",  error_description="MSIS9921: Received invalid UserInfo request. Audience 'microsoft:identityserver:21660d0d-93e8-45db-b770-45db974d432d'  in the access token is not same as the identifier of the UserInfo relying party trust 'urn:microsoft:userinfo'."`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What grant are you using? Postman flow - https://gist.github.com/nzpcmad/ab979533ba673ae837d7e3a607b9d5c1

Comment: parameters.Add("grant_type", "authorization_code");

Comment: Is there any way you made it working?

Answer (score 0):

I also recently got this error using ADFS with the ASP.NET Core OpenIDConnect providers.  In my case, disabling the UserInfo request altogether resolved the issue:

```
var openIdOptions = new OpenIdConnectOptions
{
  ...
  GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = false
};
```

After doing this, I still had the claims that I needed for my app - email, SID, name, etc.  I'm sure there are scenarios where this would not work, but it's good to know you might not need /userinfo at all.  I would still be interested in knowing why the token returned from ADFS can't be used to call /userinfo, and how to fix it in ASP.NET OpenIDConnect providers.

Comment: I found the same resolution, but now I'd like to use UserInfo endpoint _offline_ with the access token to monitor attributes of the user (specifically - are they still enabled at the IP), so I'm trying to figure out how to make it work again...

Comment: I too would really like to know how to make this work.  Spring has some nice libraries that 'just work' with other OIDC providers.  It would take some effort to make it avoid the /userinfo endpoint

Answer (score -2):

Just set the resource accordingly:

```
options.Resource = "urn:microsoft:userinfo";
```